# How do i convert mov RAXto lea RAX?

Tags: c++, hex, kernel, opcode

I have a question about opcode
Have i converted it correctly to lea rax?
also, how do i converty jmp rax to call rax?

```
0x48, 0xB8 // mov rax, [xxx]
0xFF, 0xE0, // jmp rax
```

How do i convert his to

```
lea rax, [xxx]
call rax
```

Comment: I don't think so. `0x4C, 0xB8` is the first part of x86-64 instruction `rex.WR movabs $(some value),%rax`. `lea (absolute address),%rax` looks like beginning with `0x48, 0x8D`.

Comment: The `lea` or `load effective address` looks like you are using `kernel` addresses.  Is this correct?

Comment: Correct
I am trying to convert 
"mov rax, [xxx]" to "lea rax [xxx]"
"jmp rax" to "call rax"

Updated thread text so it explains better